# scala operations on part of RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to Scala and I am trying to do something for a project:

I generated a RDD: RDD

```
[UserID1, Date1, Value1]
[UserID1, Date2, Value2]
[UserID1, Date3, Value3]
[UserID2, Date1, Value1]
[UserID3, Date1, Value1]
```

I wish to run a function on this RDD that generates RDD

```
[UserID1, FunctionResult1, FunctionResult2]
[UserID1, FunctionResult3, FunctionResult4]
[UserID2, FunctionResult1, FunctionResult2]
```

The way this function should work is:
1, groupBy UserID, and sort the date on ascending order (I have already formatted the date into an INT: 20150225.

2, take the first Date and the Second Date and find the number of Day between them.

3, take the first Value and the Second Value, find the difference between them.

record these value to Function Results, proceed to process the second Date and third Date and the second and third Value.

If the input is 5 rows x 3 column, the result should be 4 rows x 3 column.

So far, I have tried to do reduceByKey on the RDD, but it only generates a single row in the output. So I was wondering if there is any other efficient way to do this, perhaps without looping? My current code looks like this

```
val basicsearchprofile = basicsearch.map(x=>(x._1,(x._2,x._3).reduceByKey((a,b)=> funcdiff(a,b))
```

// x._1 is the User ID, x._2 is the Date, x._3 is the Value;

```
def funcdiff(a:(Date,Value),b:(Date,Value)):(Day,value) =
  {
        val diffdays = (b._1%100 - a._1%100) + ((b._1/100)%100)- (a._1/100)%100))*30 + ((a._1/10000)%100 - (b._1/10000)%100))*365 //difference between days

        val diffvalue = Math.abs(a._2 - b._2)
    }
      (diffdays diffvalue)
  }
```

I assume that the returned value from the function funcdiff reduces every event in pairs, and eventually reduces it to a single row? Is it possible to make it apply function funcdiff to first row with second row, record answer; next apply it to second and third row...and so on such that the returned result is an RDD of [ID, Datediff, Valuediff]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just give us the code that you have so far and we will help you fill in the gaps. Its very difficult to understand what you are doing as of now, for example - `sort the date`... do you mean sort the `rdd` by date in `tuple`s ? `first Date and the Second Date`... do you mean date from first and second `tuple`s ?  `first Value and the Second Value` ... well I could not guess anything for this. Also an example can also be used to explain the process requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark process rows parallel. As you have to do row2-row1, row3-row2, I think you can not work in parallel anymore. So you'll have to forget Spark a bit, use plain Scala and process a whole user data on a single node (each user can be processed in parallel though). For instance:

```
// First, group by user with Spark
case class Info(userId:String, date:Int, value:Int)
val infos=List(
    Info("john",20150221,10),
    Info("mary",20150221,11),
    Info("john",20150222,12),
    Info("mary",20150223,15),
    Info("john",20150223,14),
    Info("john",20150224,16),
    Info("john",20150225,18),
    Info("mary",20150225,17))
val infoRdd=sc.parallelize(infos)
val infoByIdRdd=infoRdd.map( info => (info.userId, info)).groupByKey()
// Then use plain Scala to process each user data
def infoDeltas(infos:List[Info]) = {
    // Transform [Info1, Info2, Info3] into [(Info1,Info2),(Info2,Info3)]
    val accZero:(Option[Info],List[(Info,Info)])=(None,List())
    def accInfo(last:Option[Info], list:List[(Info,Info)], info:Info) = {
        last match {
            case None => (Some(info), list)
            case Some(lastInfo) => (Some(info), list:+(lastInfo,info))
        }
    }
    val infoIntervals=infos.foldLeft(accZero)( 
        (acc,info) => accInfo(acc._1, acc._2, info)
    )._2
    // Transform [(Info1,Info2),(Info2,Info3)] into [Info2-Info1,Info3-Info2]
    infoIntervals.map(interval => interval match {case (before,after) => Info(after.userId,after.date-before.date,after.value-before.value)})
}
val infoDeltasByIdRdd=infoByIdRdd.mapValues(infos => infoDeltas(infos.toList))
```